# c# Timer in a for loop is not working as expected

Tags: c#, timer

I am quite new to c# and recently met a problem when I want to execute an Action of each item in an array, with incremental seconds, like below

```
DelayAction(1000, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[1]); }));
DelayAction(2000, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[2]); }));
DelayAction(3000, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[3]); }));
DelayAction(4000, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[4]); }));
DelayAction(5000, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[5]); }));
```

```
 public static void DelayAction(int millisecond, Action action)
        {
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += delegate
            {
                action.Invoke();
                timer.Stop();
            };

            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecond);
            timer.Start();
        }
```

The above line-by-line method works, and I can see UI updated every second. However, When I turn the line-by-line code into a for-loop, It is not working as expected (only the first item and last item is updated on UI, e.g. item 1 & 5)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    DelayAction(1000 * i, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[i]); }));
}
```

Method `Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(T)` will process some data and update the UI accordingly.

It is weird to me that I think the for loop is doing exactly the same as the 5 lines, But the behavior actually doesnot.

Can someone advice where did I go wrong? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I tried to replicate this within a test app just using the code you've supplied (I replaced Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent() with adding an item to a listview). The code you've posted works fine within the loop, could you please post the contents of Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent()

However, one error with this code is that while the Delay will multiply by the current value of "i" you need to remember that at the point your actual function is run i will be equal to 6, in my test this results in it printing "6" once per second to my list.

Comment: OMG. I think you really hit the point. Yes maybe that is the reason why only the last one seems to execute （due to the change if value of i will be always the last value after the delay)

What can I do to give a fix value for the action so make sure when it runs after several second, it takes the correct value? Many thanks！

Comment: Replied as an actual answer with a solution, let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your delayed function is using the ending value of i (in your case 6), to avoid this you can create a new local variable in each iteration of the loop:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            var current = i;
            DelayAction(1000 * i, new Action(() => { Instance_OnATSSSignalEvent(List[current]); }));
        }
```